# What is the function that returns after clicking the coupon?

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

There are certain javascripts on the cart page, it works fine when I first enter it, but when I enter the coupon code and say apply, I realized that my javascripts stopped. I have a code for this, but I could not run it.

Following my code : `jQuery`

```
 jQuery( document ).on( 'applied_coupon', function(event, coupon){
  jQuery('.woocommerce .cart .button, .woocommerce .cart input.button').hide();
});
```

Maybe this function I am calling is wrong, can anyone know the correct one and help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem, actually the function runs and stops in 1 second, I solved it by giving settimeout. I'm sharing it in case anyone needs it. have a nice day

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'applied_coupon', function(){
    setTimeout(function() { 
        alert("True");
    }, 2000);
});
```